# add new key/value to json dictionary python

Tags: python, json

I have the following json data:

```
hostcreate = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "host.create",
    "params": {
        "host": "my_host",
        "port": 10050,
        "interfaces": [{
            "type": 1,
            "main": 1,
            "useip": 1,
            "ip": "10.100.200.200",
            "dns": "",
            "port": "10050"
        }],
        "groups": [{
            "groupid": 2
        }, {
            "groupid": 22
        }]
    },
    "auth": "byese31blahblah",
    "id": 1
}
```

I can update the values of existing keys with something like this:

```
hostcreate['params']['port'] = str(newhostport)
```

However, when I try to add a new key/value to the dictionary, I get an error:

```
    hostcreate['params']['groups'][count]['groupid'] = int(eachgroupid)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm getting that error when the value of `count` is greater than the number of available slots for `groupid`.   So in other words, right now, `groupid` has 2 slots, which I can update easily.  But when I try to add a new key/value for groupid, I get the aforementioned error.

How can I resolve this?

**UPDATE:**

Here's the code (which isn't working):

```
    numofgroups = len(groupids.split(","))
    rnumofgroups = numofgroups - 1
    count = 0
    existinggids = len(hostcreate['params']['groups']) - 1
    while (count <= numofgroups):
        eachgroupid = groupids.split(",")[count]
        if count <= existinggids:
            count = count + 1
            hostcreate['params']['groups'][count]['groupid'] = int(eachgroupid)
        else:
            count = count + 1
            hostcreate['params'['groups'].append({
                'groupid':int(eachgroupid)
            })
```

every time I run this, it keeps complaining.  can anyone spot what is wrong with my code?

Comment: well group is a list with 2 elements if you want to add a new element you have to appended you can not access index 2 until the are 3 elements and so on.

Comment: This is because hostcreate['params']['groups'] is a LIST!! you have to append hostcreate['params']['groups'].append({"groupid": int(eachgroupid)} or overwrite some item accesing by index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hostcreate['params']['groups']` is a list, so you need `append` to add new item to it:

```
hostcreate['params']['groups'].append({
    'groupid':  int(eachgroupid)
})
```

---

**update**:

You didn't provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I can only guess what you want to do. The code you added at the update part can indeed be rewritten to make it more pythonic:

```
hostceate["params"]["groups"] = [{"groupid": int(g)} for g in groupids.split(",")]
```

This replace the whole list, which I see you're trying to do as you initialized count to 0 before the while loop.

Comment: I updated my original post.  can you see what I'm doing wrong with the code I posted?

Comment: I implemented your update and it worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to append to the list `hostcreate['params'['groups'].append({'groupid':int(eachgroupid)})`

Answer (score 0):

i would do something like

```
try:
    hostcreate['params']['groups'][count]['groupid'] = int(eachgroupid)

except:
    hostcreate['params']['groups'].append({})
    hostcreate['params']['groups'][count]['groupid'] = int(eachgroupid)
```

theres probably a more elegant work around, but this just appends an empty dict to the `groups` list so you can add the key:value to it